# Extjs 4.2: Get sum of values of a column

Tags: extjs, grid

I have a grid, and I want to get all the values of a column and get the sum. I've tried grid summary but I can't get it working.

This is my grid code:

```
Ext.ns('dlti.view.widget');


Ext.define('dlti.view.widget.PlaylistDetailsGrid' ,{
extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
id: 'playlist-details',
alias: 'widget.PlaylistDetailsGrid',
forceFit: true,
stripeRows: true,
selType: 'rowmodel',
autosync: true,
height: 150,
width: 950,


store: new dlti.store.PlaylistDetailsStore(),


columns: [


    {
        text: 'Filename',
        dataIndex: 'filename',
        renderer:   function renderDescTarget(val, p, record) {
            var desc = '';
            desc = '<p style="color:#000;font-size:12px;">' + val + '</p>';
            return desc;
        }
    },
    {
        text: 'Transition',
        dataIndex: 'transition',
        renderer:   function renderDescTarget(val, p, record) {
            var desc = '';
            desc = '<p style="color:#000;font-size:12px;">' + val + '</p>';
            return desc;
        }
    },
    {
        text: 'Stay Time',
        dataIndex: 'timeframe',
        renderer:   function renderDescTarget(val, p, record) {
            var desc = '';
            desc = '<p style="color:#000;font-size:12px;">' + val + '</p>';
            return desc;
        }
    }



]
 });
```

Please help me. I really need to finish my project.

**EDIT**

```
Ext.define('dlti.store.PlaylistDetailsStore', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
model: 'dlti.model.PlaylistDetailsModel',
storeId: 'playlist-details',
proxy: {
            type: 'memory',
            autosync: true,
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'result'
            }
        }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

maecy, try this if it helps:

```
    myStore.on('load', function(store, records){
        console.log(records);  //see if store has any records
        console.log(store.sum('fieldName')); //if store has any records, it would print sum of all values of fieldName column.
    }, this);
```

Answer (score 0):

The store already has this functionality:

```
Ext.define('MyModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['visits']
});

Ext.require('*');

Ext.onReady(function() {
    var s = new Ext.data.Store({
        model: MyModel,
        data: [{
            visits: 1
        }, {
            visits: 2
        }, {
            visits: 3
        }]
    });
    console.log(s.sum('visits'));
});
```

Doc link: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-sum

Comment: Can you give me a clearer version? Sorry, I don't quite understand from all the things I've tried it's all scattered in my mind.

Comment: This is as simple as it gets. I don't see how you could make that any clearer.

Comment: Get your store. Call the sum method it. Pass the field you want it to sum.

Comment: I used this code : var store = scope.getPlaylistDetaislGrid().getStore(); but obviously it's wrong. :\

Answer (score 0):

Try this new code for your store.

```
Ext.define('dlti.store.PlaylistDetailsStore', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
config: {
  model: 'dlti.model.PlaylistDetailsModel',
  storeId: 'playlist-details',
  proxy: {
            type: 'memory',
            autosync: true,
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'result'
            }
        }
 }
});
```

Comment: Since there's already a function for the store. I just want to know how do I call my store? I'm using Extjs 4.2.

Comment: add storeId config to your store and use it as Ext.getStore('StoreId').It will return you store's object.

Comment: I tried to get the certain value with this.                          var sample = Ext.getStore('playlist-details');
  console.log(sample.data.items);            - but it's not working

Comment: still nothing, all I get is [] as a result.

Answer (score 0):

i assume your grid has an ID that named "**YourGridID**"
and you have a grid with 3 column that named "**goods | qty | price**"

```
var grid = Ext.getCmp('YourGridID'),
    store = grid.getStore();

var totalPrice = store.sum('price');

console.log(totalPrice);
```

if you're not familiar with *console.log* you can use *alert* to show **totalPrice**

Answer (score 0):

```
summaryRenderer: function(value, summaryData, field) {
        // TODO: assign value to an in-scope variable
        // or pass value to another function
        console.log(value.toString());
        return value;
    }
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.